# Which is the heaviest elementary particle?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, elementary-particles

Which elementary particle has the greatest rest mass? (For the sake of this question I'll call a photon's rest mass 0, whether it is or isn't [actually, tell me if this is the right thing to do]).

Comment: have you tried looking up elementary particles on wikipedia and looking at which has the largest number under "mass"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg

Comment: Well, given that the question does not specify Standard Model particle, there could be any of dozens of answers to this question. For example, it is postulated, and highly likely, that if indeed Supersymmetric particles exist, then there are heavier ones than the SM particles. These are just one class of many postulated particles. I think you need to be more specific in your question to get an answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a quick Google search will give the answer.

Comment: It turns out the answer to this question is a black hole.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2014/04/04/moriond-2014-new-results-new-explorations-but-no-new-physics/ 
Top quark mass has been revised upward.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Top Quark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_quark), with a rest mass of approximately $\ 173.07 \space GeV/c^2$
.

Comment: ok, is bottom quark the next heaviest then?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg mass is number in top left of each box. GeV is larger than MeV.

Comment: @stanleydodds the Higgs Boson is the next heaviest fundamental particle in the standard model.